# Getting days in month when months and year are in different columns

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1rIc.jpg)

Hi I am trying to get the days in month from the attached dataframe.  The month and year are in INT format.

Tried using monthrange() but it doesn't works.  Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Here's some advice: read [ask] and [mre] before posting as you were suggested when you joined.

Comment: From your data frame, it appears that the months are simply the actual months (1 for January, 2 for Feb, and likewise) we already know the days in those months. Why don't you create an if-else statement. eg. if the month is 1, the number of days by default is 31, and so on

Comment: @PrasinusAlbus but what about February?

Comment: Check for leap year first. If it is a leap, assign the number of days to 29 otherwise 28. Here is a snippet to check for leap year: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/leap-year

Comment: @Roy how exactly do you use `monthrange`?

Comment: positions['num_days_in_mth'] = monthrange(positions['Contract Maturity Year'],positions['Contract Maturity Month']) 
I tried to use this to get month in range.  Positions is the name of my dataframe.

However I received the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

```
positions['num_days_in_mth'] = positions.apply( \
    lambda x: monthrange(x['Contract Maturity Year'], \
    x['Contract Maturity Month']), axis=1)[1])
```

Here the function `monthrange` is applied to each row, not to entire columns like in your attempt. Also the function returns (day of week for first day, number of days), so you have to choose the second value, i.e. [1].